React native, how do I destroy components created by the .map function?
I am displaying some cards when my data is loading but the issue is when the loading is complete the cards are still there, where I want them to be destroyed. I am creating all of these cards using the .map function from arrays in javascript, I haven't found anything on how I can destroy the components I have created. Take a look at the code (to note I want the components visibility to be dependent if searchValue has a value or not)
Here is the code snippet:
{searchQuery.isLoading && (
          <>
            <Spinner size="large" color="#ffffff" />
            <View flexDirection="row" flexWrap="wrap" justifyContent="center">
              {searchedValue !== null &&
                searchedValue.map((item) => <BookCard book={item} key={item.volumeInfo.title} />)}
            </View>
          </>
        )}

For anyone wondering, I am using tanstack query and expo as well for this app. Thank you so much for reading this.
I tried experimenting with some conditionals such as
            {searchValue &&
              (searchValue.length === 0 ? (
                <Text>No results found</Text>
              ) : (
                <View flexDirection="row" flexWrap="wrap" justifyContent="center">
                  {searchedValue.map((item) => (
                    <BookCard book={item} key={item.volumeInfo.title} />
                  ))}
                </View>
              ))}

but that didn't work.
I am expecting to see the components to be completely destroyed or hidden when searchValue has some sort of value in it.

are searchValue and searchedValue different things? Or just an inaccurate transcription of the original code?

searchValue and searchedValue are different things

Are you sure that your searchQuery.isLoading  value is being changed correct and makes re-render of your component?
